Any idea what can be causing cp to fail in Red Hat 8.2?
I'm copying a large file (45GB) from one filesystem to another using Red Hat 8.2. I did
% cp file /dir_in_another_filesystem

I got suspicious that something was wrong when md5sum on the /dir_in_another_filesystem/file was not the same as the original file.
Doing a diff the result was that the source and destination files were not the same, though both files have the exact same size. I checked and my cp is /usr/bin/cp the vanilla cp that comes in the Linux system can't believe would be a bug there.
Have no clue how /usr/bin/cp is it written - does it copy block by block or does it use memory maps? Any suggestion to look for culprits and what can go wrong?
The "other filesystem" is ext4 about 8TB in size mounted on a slice of raid0 two-disk WD-Red NAS 10TB each, with about 1TB free.
My system is an i9-10980XE with 256GB of DDR4 memory. I never seen anything wrong like that in Linux in my whole life. I am performing a bad-blocks scan of the whole disk to see if the disk is damaged.
Any other ideas?

Its a large file  - things could go wrong. Aside from trying to figure out what's wrong, maybe try an alternate method of moving it like rsync?

Might there be clues in the output of cp --debug ...

Bad-block scan came empty - did a non-destructive read/write test, took a bit over a day to check 8 TBytes. Now I'm going to test memory with memtest+ to see if some memory is corrupted.

I would suggest trying a different program to move the file, as Journeyman Geek suggests. Different utilities have their strengths and weaknesses.

Found the culprit - mystery solved.
Testing memory revealed that a tiny region of the 256GB of memory was faulty. That explains why during the copy execution — most likely it uses mmap — of a very large file, a few bytes were mangled.
After removing a couple of memory sticks - one of them is the one damaged - I was left with 192GB of memory, but now I was able to copy the file without any problems, md5sums are identical on both filesystems, and a diff shows both binary files are identical.
